# import Vue from node_modules using a prefix

Tags: vue.js, codeigniter, npm, phpstorm

I'm setting up my dev environment under Ubuntu 20.04, with the following tools:

- PhpStorm 2020.3 as IDE
- CodeIgniter v4
- Vue 3.x
- Tailwind CSS+UI

I created a test project and following the docs I did:

```
npm install tailwindcss@latest
npm install @headlessui/vue @heroicons/vue
npm install vue@next
```

and the other stuff to create the skeleton of CodeIgniter project.
Then I wrote a simple "Hello World" Vue application:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="output.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
    <script type="module" src="test1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="hello-vue" class="demo">
    {{ message }}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
const HelloVueApp = {
    data() {
        return {
            message: 'Hello Vue!!'
        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(HelloVueApp).mount('#hello-vue')
```

It works!
But as far as I understand this makes no sense: I used `Vue.js` from a CDN while I installed it locally using `npm`.

If I remove the `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>`  line I need to import Vue before I can use it.

It is contained under the `node_modules` folder.
So I tried:

```
import Vue from "/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.cjs.js"
```

and also:

```
import Vue from "../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.cjs.js"
```

But in both cases it does not find the file (error 404).
What is the correct syntax?

Of course the file exists, if I type this from the project's root folder:

```
$ ls node_modules/vue/dist/vue.cjs.js
node_modules/vue/dist/vue.cjs.js
```

Comment: Vue isn't supposed to be used without build step. It works itself but third-party libs are commonly not. And apart from Vue, client-side libs aren't ready to be used with native ES modules like `<script type="module"`. `import Vue from "../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.cjs.js"` - you're trying to use CommonJS module in ES modules. This isn't workable with native ES modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing client side javascript and server side javascript.

The `node_modules` directory is living in your server and thus is not available to the client, the client being who requested your initial html.
When you do

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<script type="module" src="test1.js"></script>
```

You are making Vue accessible to your client side js because it gets imported from `https://unpkg.com/vue@next`. If you want to avoid that and use your npm packages you need to use a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). It will look at the modules you import in the js files you wrote and prepare a *new* js file which will contain all the needed stuff (both your code and the vue module code).
If you set up everything correctly you should be able to end up writing a js file with:

```
import Vue from "vue"

const HelloVueApp = {
    data() {
        return {
            message: 'Hello Vue!!'
        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(HelloVueApp).mount('#hello-vue')
```

without the need for the

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```

line.

Comment: Got it. I read about `webpack` but I thought I don't need it. Thanks for pointing it out.